# Place element in DOM in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

Say we have an array in scope, which contains canvas elements.

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.canvasElements =
 [document.createElement('canvas'), document.createElement('canvas')];
```

**HTML**

```
<element replace-with="currentCanvas" ng-click="alert('clicked')"></element>
```

`currentCanvas` is a variable which will reference to the currently selected canvas in array.

```
$scope.currentCanvas = null;
```

And say we changed `$scope.currentCanvas` like this:

```
$scope.currentCanvas = $scope.canvasElements[0];
```

Now the currently selected canvas element (`$scope.currentCanvas`) should replace the `<element>` in DOM.

All events attached to `<element>` I want to be transferred to the new element (in this case canvas), which replaces it.

And if the variable `$scope.currentCanvas` changes, like this:

```
$scope.currentCanvas = $scope.canvasElements[1];
```

Same thing should happen (I think scope watch should be used here).

Any solutions??

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you need to satisfy these conditions and which exact events you need to transfer:

> All events attached to `<element>` I want to be transferred to the new
>   element (in this case canvas), which replaces it

but, assuming `click` event is enough for you, the easiest and fastest way to achieve your goals, is the following directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('fakeElement', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { replaceWith: '=' },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(
                'replaceWith',
                () => elem.html('').append(scope.replaceWith)
            );                  
        },
        template: '<div class="wrapper"></div>'
    };
});
```

The directive listens to changes in `replaceWith` parameter and modifies content of a directive accordingly.

There's no need to transfer `click` handler to new element due to bubbling nature of an event.

You could play with it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0jnjJkO18eg1c0vIzTqS?p=preview). Each click on a `<div>` replaces current `<div>` with next in line.

In case you want to dynamically replace not just regular HTML elements, but custom directives, you have to also `$compile` new element before appending it.

Answer (score 0):

### The code below answers my question!

The main thing in this code is `'el'` directive, the rest is just for demonstrating how the directive works.

Hope this helps other developers too!

```js
angular.element.prototype.cloneCanvas = function(){
  if (!this.is('canvas')) return this;
  var canvas = this[0];
  var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
  newCanvas.width = canvas.width;
  newCanvas.height = canvas.height;
  context.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
  return newCanvas;
};

angular.module('app', [])

.directive('el', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      element: '='
    },
  compile: function(element, attrs){
    return function(scope){
      var currentElement = element;
      scope.$watch('element', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue && typeof newValue === "object") {
          var newOb = angular.element(newValue)[0];
          if (typeof newOb.style === "object") {
            var clone = angular.element(newOb).is('canvas') ? 
              angular.element(newOb).cloneCanvas() : angular.element(newOb).clone();
            var attrs = angular.element(element)[0].attributes;
            angular.forEach(attrs, function(attr){
              angular.element(clone).attr(attr.name, attr.value);
            });
            var clone = $compile(clone)(scope.$parent);
            currentElement.replaceWith(clone);
            currentElement = clone;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
  };
})

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.canvasElements = [document.createElement('canvas'),document.createElement('canvas'),document.createElement('canvas')];
  
  $scope.canvasElements.forEach(function(canvas, i){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#EEE";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.font="20px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Canvas "+(i+1),7,55);
    ctx.save();
  });
  
  $scope.currentCanvas = $scope.canvasElements[0];
  
  $scope.setNextCanvasAsCurrent = function(){
    $scope.currentCanvas = $scope.canvasElements.indexOf($scope.currentCanvas) < 0 ? $scope.canvasElements[0] : $scope.canvasElements.indexOf($scope.currentCanvas) == $scope.canvasElements.length-1 ? $scope.canvasElements[0] : $scope.canvasElements[ $scope.canvasElements.indexOf($scope.currentCanvas) + 1]
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

  <el element="currentCanvas"></el>

  <br>
  <button ng-click="setNextCanvasAsCurrent()">Set Next Canvas As Current</button>
  
  
  {{canvasElements.indexOf(currentCanvas) + 1}}
  /
  {{canvasElements.length}}


</div>
```